# Generate a version number of my site with git?

Tags: php, git, versioning

I am building a PHP/Yii application. While developing and testing on different machines, I'd like to be able to quickly see in the footers if the version I am seeing is the latest. So basically I want to generate some kind of version number every time I modify something.

I was thinking since I use Git (and GitHub) I could use some of the meta data generated at every commit?
How could I achieve this?

Note: I'd like to avoid using command-line stuff as my current hosting won't allow me to do this.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure you can. What is your question?

Comment: My question then was "How?". I've updated it.

Comment: Well git *is* commandline. So make a better suggestion I'd say. Also how do you use git if your hoster does not allow it?

Comment: I am using a host that pulls my git automatically. https://www.engineyard.com/products/orchestra

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a git hook to create a txt file in the root folder of your app to keep track of the version (or tag, or whatever) of the current deployed code.

Just a 30 sec. example (search google for more details and how to use hooks in git) put in the `.git/hooks` folder a file named `pre-commit` and add this shell code:

```
#!/bin/sh
rm version.txt -i
git describe --tags >> version.txt
git add version.txt
```

Comment: I like this idea, could you go into more details?

Comment: Have you considered doing any research yourself, given a starting point? Take a look at [`man githooks`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html) for instance.

Comment: I did this:
`#!/bin/sh
rm version.txt -i
git rev-parse --short HEAD >> version.txt
git add version.txt`

Answer (score 0):

If you deploy with Capistrano, one very serious possibility is to read the 'REVISION' file from the base of the site. If you deploy from a git repo, it will be the commit SHA.

Comment: I managed to retrieve the commit SHA via the filesystem. Not very pretty looking but better than nothing!